# How to reconcile the formulas of chain rule in cases $X \subseteq \mathbb K$ and $X$ is a general Banach space?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, definition, banach-spaces, chain-rule

My textbook presents the chain rule in case $X \subseteq \mathbb K$ as follows:

> [image]

In this case, $(g \circ f)^{\prime}(a)=g^{\prime}(f(a)) f^{\prime}(a)$. Clearly, $g^{\prime}(f(a)) f^{\prime}(a)$ denotes the arithmetic product of $g^{\prime}(f(a))$ and $f^{\prime}(a)$. Hence $(g \circ f)^{\prime}(a) = g^{\prime}(f(a)) \cdot f^{\prime}(a)$. It seems to me that $f^{\prime}(a)$ is a value in $\mathbb K$, not a bounded linear map in $\mathcal L(\mathbb K, \mathbb K)$. Similarly, $g^{\prime}(f(a))$ is a value in $E$, not a bounded linear map in $\mathcal L(\mathbb K, E)$.

Here is its general form:

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcQqC.png]

In my understanding, $\partial f\left(x_{0}\right) \in \mathcal L(E,F)$ and $\partial g\left(f\left(x_{0}\right)\right) \in \mathcal L(F,G)$. As such, $\partial g\left(f\left(x_{0}\right)\right) \partial f\left(x_{0}\right)$ does not denote the arithmetic product of $\partial g\left(f\left(x_{0}\right)\right)$ and $\partial f\left(x_{0}\right)$. Instead, it is the function composition of $\partial g\left(f\left(x_{0}\right)\right)$ and $\partial f\left(x_{0}\right)$, i.e. $$\partial g\left(f\left(x_{0}\right)\right) \partial f\left(x_{0}\right) = \partial g\left(f\left(x_{0}\right)\right) \circ \partial f\left(x_{0}\right) \in \mathcal L(E,G)$$

---

**My question:**

Could you please elaborate on how the chain rule in these two cases coincide? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: If $F$ is a one-dimensional vector space over the field $k$, then a linear map $g: F \to F$ is precisely the same thing as scalar multiplication by some element of $k$. So in particular, there is a canonical isomorphism $k \to \mathcal{L}(k, k)$, since $k$ is a one-dimensional vector space. Now if $v$ is any vector in a $k$-vector space $V$, then we can think of $v$ as being equivalent to the linear map $i_v: k \to V$ defined by $i_v(1) = v$, so we have an isomorphism of vector spaces $\mathcal{L}(k, V) \to V$. Now consider what function composition looks like under these isomorphisms.

Comment: Thank you so much @Joppy :) I got it.